# Microsoft SQL Server: Generate a sequence number, per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I'm tasked to create an increasing sequence number per day for a project. Multiple processes (theoretically on multiple machines) need to generate this. It ends up as

```
[date]_[number]
```

like

```
20101215_00000001
20101215_00000002
...
20101216_00000001
20101216_00000002
...
```

Since I'm using an SQL Server (2008) in this project anyway, I tried to do this with T-SQL/SQL magic. This is where I am right now:

I created a table containing the sequence number like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SequenceTable](
    [SequenceId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My naive solution so far is a trigger, after insert, that sets the SequenceNumber:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[GenerateMessageId]
ON  [dbo].[SequenceTable] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- The ID of the record we just inserted
DECLARE @InsertedId bigint;
SET @InsertedId = (SELECT SequenceId FROM Inserted)

-- The next SequenceNumber that we're adding to the new record
DECLARE @SequenceNumber int;
SET @SequenceNumber = (
    SELECT SequenceNumber FROM
    (
        SELECT SequenceId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SequenceDate ORDER BY SequenceDate ASC) AS SequenceNumber
        FROM SequenceTable
    ) tmp
    WHERE SequenceId = @InsertedId
)

-- Update the record and set the SequenceNumber
UPDATE 
    SequenceTable
SET 
    SequenceTable.SequenceNumber = ''+@SequenceNumber
FROM
    SequenceTable
INNER JOIN
    inserted ON SequenceTable.SequenceId = inserted.SequenceId
END
```

As I said, that's rather naive, and keeps a full day of rows just for a single number that I never need again anyway: I do an insert, get the generated sequence number and ignore the table afterwards. No need to *store* them on my side, I just need to generate them once. In addition I'm pretty sure this isn't going to scale well, gradually getting slower the more rows the table contains (i.e. I don't want to fall into that "worked on my dev machine with 10.000 rows only" trap).

I guess the current way was more me looking at SQL with some creativity, but the result seems to be - erm - less useful. More clever ideas?

Comment: Depending on what you can realisticly expect to be inserted a day, you might create a table and pre-fill it with combinations for every day for the next 100 years. After that, pick and remove the MIN sequence for your current day.

Comment: Your trigger code is inherently unsafe for multi-row inserts (since it assumes that inserted contains a single row)

Comment: Since I'm the only one inserting - that's fine. It's just correctness and performance I'm worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget about that `SequenceTable`. You should just create two columns on your final table: a datetime and a identity. And if you really need them to be combined, just add a computed column.

I guess it would be something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable] (
    [SequenceId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] AS (CAST(SequenceDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(SequenceID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)) PERSISTED
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

That way will scale - you are not creating any kind of intermediary or temporary data.

**Edit** I still think that the answer above is the best solution. BUT there is another option: computed columns *can* reference functions...

So do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextSequence (
    @sequenceDate DATE,
    @sequenceId BIGINT
) RETURNS VARCHAR(17)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date VARCHAR(8)
    SET @date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @sequenceDate, 112)

    DECLARE @number BIGINT
    SELECT
        @number = COALESCE(MAX(aux.SequenceId) - MIN(aux.SequenceId) + 2, 1)
    FROM
        SomeTable aux
    WHERE
        aux.SequenceDate = @sequenceDate
        AND aux.SequenceId < @sequenceId

    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(17)
    SET @result = @date + '_' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(@number AS VARCHAR(8)), 8)
    RETURN @result
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable] (
    [SequenceId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] AS (dbo.GetNextSequence(SequenceDate, SequenceId))
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO SomeTable(SequenceDate) values ('2010-12-14')
INSERT INTO SomeTable(SequenceDate) values ('2010-12-15')
INSERT INTO SomeTable(SequenceDate) values ('2010-12-15')
INSERT INTO SomeTable(SequenceDate) values ('2010-12-15')
GO

SELECT * FROM SomeTable
GO

SequenceId           SequenceDate SequenceNumber
-------------------- ------------ -----------------
1                    2010-12-14   20101214_00000001
2                    2010-12-15   20101215_00000001
3                    2010-12-15   20101215_00000002
4                    2010-12-15   20101215_00000003

(4 row(s) affected)
```

It's ugly, but works, right? :-) No temporary table whatsoever, no views, no triggers, and it will have a decent performance (with at least an index over `SequenceId` and `SequenceDate`, of course). And you **can** remove records (since and identity is being used for the resulting computed field).

Comment: Nope - this won't help unfortunately: That misses the "restart on a new day" boundary. I need a new sequence per day, starting at 0 or 1.

Comment: So you have no other option than do something like you are already doing. You need to know it is a "new day", so you need to read previous records - which is not very smart btw, but that's only my opinion.

Comment: Smart or not is not up for discussion, unfortunately - it's a requirement I have and cannot change. Other alternatives that I try to remove are processes locking on global mutexes and reading/updating an ini file, which isn't smart either and doesn't work across machine boundaries.

Comment: Checking that now. It would certainly do the requirements (I fumbled around with scalar functions but wasn't able to come up with something that ~works~ before). I give it a spin right now and check the performance with millions of rows though. Sad, that I cannot use the generated value in an output clause to replace the Insert/Select with just an Insert. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Why don't you just use the date/time? Is there a good technical reason you need this column? I'd argue until I was blue in the face that it was nonsense unless the person that required it could give me a good reason it was needed..

Comment: @Charleh you should ask that to the OP, I guess. The OP wanted a sequence number **per day**; I just provided an answer for that specific need.

Comment: Sorry thought I had, that's the problem with SO on mobile phones :D

Answer (score 2):

If you can create the actual table with a different name, and perform all of your other operations through a view, then it might fit the bill. It does also require that no transaction is ever deleted (so you'd need to add appropriate trigger/permission on the view/table to prevent that):

```
create table dbo.TFake (
    T1ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    T1Date datetime not null,
    Val1 varchar(20) not null,
    constraint PK_T1ID PRIMARY KEY (T1ID)
)
go
create view dbo.T
with schemabinding
as
    select
        T1Date,
        CONVERT(char(8),T1Date,112) + '_' + RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(varchar(8),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(char(8),T1Date,112) ORDER BY T1ID)),8) as T_ID,
        Val1
    from
        dbo.TFake
go
insert into T(T1Date,Val1)
select '20101201','ABC' union all
select '20101201','DEF' union all
select '20101202','GHI'
go
select * from T
```

Result:

```
T1Date  T_ID    Val1
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000 20101201_00000001   ABC
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000 20101201_00000002   DEF
2010-12-02 00:00:00.000 20101202_00000001   GHI
```

---

You can, of course, also hide the date column from the view and make it default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Thanks. While that looks far better than my approach (+1 for that), it's not viable. I'm going to generate lots of these things (that's why the number is formatted as 8 digits) per day. Never removing rows is not an option.

Comment: @Benjamin - you can delete rows, provided you delete all rows which pertain to a particular day - otherwise the generated ID values of some rows (which you've left behind) may change.

Comment: you could improve it even more by creating an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), right? Your answer is almost there anyway...

Comment: @rsenna - it's where I was heading, before being abruptly halted by the use of the OVER() - it's not allowed in indexed views. But it's why I'd set up for it with schemabinding.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceTableStorage (
    SequenceId bigint identity not null,
    SequenceDate date NOT NULL,
    OtherCol int NOT NULL,
)

CREATE VIEW SequenceTable AS
SELECT x.SequenceDate, (CAST(SequenceDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(SequenceID - (SELECT min(SequenceId) + 1 FROM SequenceTableStorage y WHERE y.SequenceDate = x.SequenceDate) AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)) AS SequenceNumber, OtherCol
  FROM SequenceTableStorage x
```

If you create an index on the SequenceDate and SequenceId, I don't think the performance will be too bad.

**Edit:**

The code above might miss some sequence numbers, for example if a transaction inserts a row and then rolls back (the identity value will then be lost in space).

This can be fixed with this view, whose performance might or might not be good enough.

```
CREATE VIEW SequenceTable AS
SELECT SequenceDate, (CAST(SequenceDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + RIGHT('0000000000' + row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY SequenceDate ORDER BY SequenceId)
  FROM SequenceTableStorage
```

My guess is that it will be good enough until you start getting millions of sequence numbers per day.

Comment: This seems to be promising. With exactly this approach performance is still poor if I have millions of rows (in spite of indices). If I can rely on Min(SequenceId) being equal to Top 1 SequenceId I can improve the performance dramatically. Now I'm struggling to prove/make sure that this replacement is correct...

Comment: Min(SequenceId) shouldn't perform bad as long as it is indexed together with SequenceDate. SQL Server is perfectly able to realize it can find the minimum value from the index.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way to create session codes for user logging and its working;

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSessionSeqCode]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(15) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Count INT;
DECLARE @SeqNo VARCHAR(15)

SELECT @Count = ISNULL(COUNT(SessionCode),0)
FROM UserSessionLog
WHERE SUBSTRING(SessionCode,0,9) =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)

SET @SeqNo =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) +'-' + FORMAT(@Count+1,'D3');

RETURN @SeqNo
END
```

generated codes are: 
'20170822-001'
,'20170822-002'
,'20170822-003'

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind the numbers not starting at one you could use `DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())` which is the number of days since 1-1-1900.  That will increment every day.

Comment: They want it to increment multiple times per day e.g.`20101215_00000001`, `20101215_00000002`, ...